# Multiple definition of variables

Tags: c++

C++ beginner here.

I'm writing a simple program which is divided in three sheets:

**foo.h** (#includes all the needed libraries, all the program variables and declarations of all functions)

**foo.cpp** (#includes foo.h, contains definition of foo.h functions)

**main.cpp** (#includes foo.h and of course contains main function)

I compile with command: **g++ *cpp -o time**

The error I get is:

**/tmp/cc0sNZgq.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of 'variableName'** for every variable declared in foo.h. Followed by:

**collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

**Note: I already put include guards in header file foo.h**

I was trying to have a header which contained all variables and declaration of functions so that main.cpp remained as simple and clean as possible.

I've looked online and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You have the *definitions* of the variables in the header, rather than just the *declarations*. So you have the definition appearing in two compiled files. [Read up on the `extern` keyword.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), or make the variables `static` members of a class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not put your variables into the header files. This will mean that each .cpp file including the header will have its own copy of the variables.

If you want to share global variables across multiple .cpp, then you should declare them in one .cpp and use *extern* in the header file. But I would recommend not using global variables unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I put them though? Both **foo.cpp** and **main.cpp** need them.

Comment: Put them in one of the .cpp and in the other use extern.

Comment: It seems like `foo.h` and `foo.cpp` go together as a single component, so put the declarations with `extern` in `foo.h`, and the definitions in `foo.cpp`. If they are not a single component, then give them different names!